# Rolling remember me cookies with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-security

I am using Spring's [TokenBasedRememberMeServices](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html) and `RememberMeAuthenticationFilter` to identify previously remembered users by a Base-64 encoded cookie. As per the interface contract, the cookie will only be set/renewed after every **interactive** login. This means that the cookie's TTL doesn't get renewed after each successful cookie-based login.

I'm now looking for a way to use TokenBasedRememberMeServices to extend the period after each successful login (interactive or non-interactive). I was thinking of adding a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to the filter, or overriding `onSuccessfulAuthentication` in the same class, but I'm curious if a) any of you came across the same problem and b) why that's no built-in option of the RememberMeServices.

PS: "Rolling remember me cookies" have obvious security disadvantages as one cookie could basically keep you logged in forever without knowing the password, but let's keep this aside for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have already fully answered your own question. The proper way to handle it would be implementing an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. This is the right place for custom logic executed upon success. You also explained why this scenario is rarely encountered, and at the same time, why there is no out-of-the-box solution. I, for one, can not say I've seen this behavior in the wild on the web.

Comment: Huh? A ton of sites have this, including StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

When I am reading the code for [`TokenBasedRememberMeServices`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java#L187) to give alternative answer, I found out this line:

```
 public void onLoginSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication successfulAuthentication) {
    int tokenLifetime = calculateLoginLifetime(request, successfulAuthentication);
    long expiryTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // SEC-949
    expiryTime += 1000L* (tokenLifetime < 0 ? TWO_WEEKS_S : tokenLifetime);

    String signatureValue = makeTokenSignature(expiryTime, username, password);

    setCookie(new String[] {username, Long.toString(expiryTime), signatureValue}, tokenLifetime, request, response);
```

As you can see, there is a mechanism to lengthen the cookies lifetime everytime user logged in successfully, by setting the `tokenLifetime` to negative value.

If you see [SEC-949](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-949), it described the functionality:

> I've added support for this to TokenBasedRememberMeServices. It allows
> the use of a negative value as the tokenValiditySeconds property. If
> the value is negative, the token expiryTime (as used in the signature)
> will remain at the default of 14 days, but the cookie maxAge will be
> set to the negative value, preventing it from being persisted on the
> client when the browser closes.
>
> PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices will reject a negative value on initialization.

In case you want more customization, I suppose you'll need to extend the class, or modify the class and send patch to spring.

Comment: Are you sure that it lengthens the lifetime? From my point of view it just deletes the cookie after closing the browser. ```onLoginSuccess``` still only gets called after an interactive login, doesn't it?